# jQuery deeplinking - Workaround not working

Tags: jquery, triggers, click

I am currently working a project using an altered version of isotope filtering. There is a portfolio gallery on a subpage, which is filterable with isotope jquery filter. I am using jQuery 1.8.3.

What I am trying to do, is to put a deeplink to a specific portfolio category on the front page. I would like to add a hashtag and have it being recognized by jQuery, which then fires an event to simulate a click on the filter button according to the hashtag.

Everything works fine, except for the click.

This is my code for the click event (I've sorted out the other stuff, which is working fine anyway):

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
jQuery(jQuery("a[data-value='cat1']")[0]).trigger("click");
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the click event do? also, `jQuery(jQuery("a[data-value='cat1']")[0])` can be shortened to `jQuery("a[data-value='cat1']").eq(0)`

Comment: it was an unnecessary leftover. just removed it. actually all it should do, is "clicking" this link: <a href="#" class="gdl-button active" data-value="cat1">cat1</a>

and it does, when entered in chrome console... :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .on()

Take a look at this documentation.

http://api.jquery.com/on/